# How to paint tileable

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tiles

I want to paint an image that needs to be tileable from the beginning. Converting it to a tileable later on would look weird.

How can I tell Photoshop to paint the image tileable?

This is tileable sculpting in blender, I am looking for the same concept in PS.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to on-the-fly update/draw as you are in blender but basically what you have is a [pattern](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-patterns.html)

Comment: @CAI will this convert my image to a tileable one?

Comment: [I find your name un-amusing. . .](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what a pattern is, an image you can use as a tileable fill. You define a pattern then set it as a fill in layer styles.

Comment: Illustrator sortof has this

Answer (score 1):

## Define a custom pattern

The easiest way to create a pattern is to create a new document at the size you want, but you can create a pattern from a selection too. The easiest way to do that is to create a rectangle at the desired size first and work from that.

[image]

Draw your pattern on a new layer

[image]

<kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> the layer thumbnail of the guide rectangle you created to make a selection. Then go to **Edit → Define Pattern...**

[image]

Set a layer style on the layer you want to fill with your pattern. Apply a **Pattern Overlay** set to your new pattern.

[image]

*Note—The pattern overlay will is only an overlay so it needs something to overlay (i.e. it won't fill an empty layer). So you will need to overlay a shape with an existing fill or you can use a solid color layer etc.*

Comment: Yes, but the pattern doesn't auto-repeat smoothly, and I think that's what the OP is after.

Comment: I don't think so.. OPs blender example repeats exactly the same way as a PS pattern or the same as if you manually tiled an image. If you want a repeating pattern (i.e. a pattern that goes over the edges of the tile) that is something you need to design and a completely different issue